# Are reset password links a bad idea?

Tags: security, passwords, password-recovery

We have a password reset web application. The application sends out an confirmation code to an alternative e-mail. My manager believes it is not a good idea to include a link to the page were you have to enter the code.

I see his argument. However, the helpdesk has been overwhelmed with users who are confused about the process. I'm assuming this is because many our users browse using only one tab/window and navigate out of our web application to check their e-mail for the confirmation code.

**My question**: How should we approach this issue? I would like to alleviate helpdesk and, in turn, make the process pain free for our users. Any suggestions?

### Clarification

He believes that we are doing the user a disservice by training them to click links from a sender that cannot be verified (in this case, it's an automatic message with a "no-reply" address). This, would in turn, make users more susceptible to phishing attempts which we've had a lot of issues with in our organization.

Comment: why does your manager think linking to a page where you enter code is a bad idea?

Comment: What questions was the helpdesk asked? Why do you think the use of tabs is relevant?

Comment: @Martin Question "I got this code and I try to enter it but nothing happens". They are entering it in the password field instead of going to the "Enter you confirmation code" link on the homepage.

Comment: @stillstanding He believes that we are doing the user a disservice by training them to click links from a sender that cannot be verified (in this case, an automatic message).

Comment: Maybe you could put in the e-mail, or on the confirm page after the user clicks "forgot password", a warning to please check the e-mail and make sure the URL points to the right website?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The user *expects* the mail to come, as your service will point out on the screen when he asks for it. And "false" mails will come into your mailbox either way.

Comment: @Eiko It is not an issue with the user expecting the e-mail. It is more about having the user trust links in an e-mail.

Comment: @Nimmy: The sender of a message can be forged. You should train users to check if the link leads to the correct address instead.

Comment: @stillstanding I made that point my response to him +1.

Comment: Perhaps a single sign-on process for your organization should be considered. You might want to integrate the authentication modules of your your Web applications with your e-mail service. If users forget the password for one service, he/she has to reset all.

Comment: @stillstanding We do already have a shared credentials system. We use LDAP for authentication. The problem isn't the authentication. It's the confusion that we are causing by not sending out the link to the password reset confirmation code form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sending links is the standard way of doing it. If a customer is really worried about the integrity of this email account, he better gets that sorted out first.

Essentially you don't gain extra security by not sending the link, but you gain a lot of comfort. Just do it like everyone else - put it in there (time limited).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing on the top of mind would be the option to have a unique identifier in the e-mail's subject an have the customers reply to that mail.

Then an automated script checks 'password-forgotten@mycompany.de' for emails with the subject 'Re: Forgot your password? [UNIQUEID]'. The script would then mail them their new password.

Since most users won't modify the subject when hitting "Reply To" and won't do a "Compose new mail" and enter the recipient address manually, chances are big, incoming mails to "password-forgotten" will have that UNIQUEID in the subject.

Plus helpdesk would only have help those that actually modify the email's "Subject". ;-)

There are security considerations, though. Maybe your manager might argue, that anyone might send a forged "Forgor your password" mail and set the "Reply-To" header to the attacker's address. The processing script has to intercept these attempts of forgery...

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why the link shouldn't be included, especially if the code is something like a hash because the chances of somebody cracking that are slim to none.

You could however, add an extra protection to the page where the code is being inserted and limit the number of tries to something like 3. For even more protection, send the email address to that page as well, and allow 3 tries per email address instead of 3 tries / IP, which can be easily bypassed.